# Invalid CSS only in application.css.sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

If my application.css.sass has no extra space in custom css like:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

 .locale {
   float: right;
   margin: -0.25em 0.1em;
 }
```

I have the usual error: `Invalid CSS after "right": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"`

But if I add an extra space or more, I don't get the CSS error but **the style is not added**:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

   .locale {
     float: right;
     margin: -0.25em 0.1em;
   }
```

With the rest of my custom scss I don't have this problem.
I have other applications without this problem.

Comment: Why would you make changes in you `application.css`? Just make a new file, like `main.css.scss` and put all of your styles there.

Comment: Thanks vucko. Is a possibility, yes. I'm following the "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" and is coded in this way. I no have problem with other apps, only with this one. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.sass` extension -> `application.css`?

Comment: @Vucko all the require assets stop to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your file name to `application.scss` as files with the `.sass` extension use indented syntax (white space sensitive). This explains your errors.

[Here](http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better) is a debate on which syntax to use.